# Are Simultaneous Tests and Multiple Comparison same concepts?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, terminology, simultaneous-test

I Really Can't find some exact definition to the `Simultaneous tests`. So I am not sure if `Simultaneous tests` and `Multiple Comparison` are same concepts or not.

I also need a **source** (Book or Article) to the definitions.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding:

Simultaneous tests: The null hypothesis has multiple restrictions. One test statistics is derived and one p-value is given. For example: In linear model. null hypothesis can be $\beta_1=0$ and $\beta_2 = 0$. Then F value, finally one p-value.

Multiple Comparison: Multiple null hypotheses with multiple p-values. For example: From null hypothesis $\beta_1 = 0$, one p-value is generated; from null hypothesis $\beta_2 = 0$, another p-value is produced.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the correct terminology is "multiple comparison". It means you do multiple statistical inferences together. You don't need a book for the definition (read Wikipedia).

Comment: So you mean Both are same and "Multiple Comparison" is better?